# Wrongful accusation of holding fake degree

Tags: human-resources, legal, canada, government, rights

My friend recently joined a large federal government organisation in Canada. A few of months into the job, she's applying to another job within the org. During the application, she's being accused of holding a fake engineering degree from one of the top universities in Canada. In fact, I know her degree is legitimate. The reason given is that it "looks fake". It's scanned and looks different than the typical phone photo. Both the university and the org are saying this. Sounds like the university didn't actually check. She didn't change her name.

She is emotionally distraught due to this. She happens to belong to a minority group in an area of the country where sentiments against this group are high. It is hard not to think this might be relevant. Maybe it's a mistaken identity, though the chances of fooling this particular organisation is very low. I'd argue there are more chances of malice.

The university in question has been unresponsive so far. This is insane.

I suggested that she get a lawyer, reach out to organizations that handle human rights complaints, and to investigative journalists.

Has anyone heard of this happening before?  advice on this? What options does my friend have?

Update after accepting answer: She managed to receive a notice of correction from the university. Thank you for sharing your thoughts, experiences, and suggestions.

Comment: Who is accusing her? Her manager? Is the accusation in writing? Has it been detailed what your friend needs to do in order to prove their degree?

Comment: And has your friend gone through the correct process at the university to get their academic transcript, or did she send an email pleading for help? It's not the university's responsibility to engage the employer on their behalf, but they may be obliged to provide a digital copy of the transcript.

Comment: "The university in question has been unresponsive so far." This does not make sense. Universities provide official transcripts and diplomas all the time. At most, all that should be necessary to clear this up is to fill out a form and pay a nominal fee to have documentation sent to the employer.

Comment: Sure, agreed on the official process, however, I don't expect the university nor the org to use the phrase "looks fake" and then disqualify her application without actual verification, without following the procedure themselves if they have one to obtain proofs, or notifying my friend about proceeding with this. This appears to be a decoy in the disqualification. It's unprofessional to say the least and I'd argue reckless and possibly malicious IMHO

Comment: Surely the university has documentation, records, and transcripts regarding her degree? Surely it isn't legal to withhold those from her? How has she attempted to get a copy of these records and documents from the university?

Comment: Any reputable university will have a process in order to get academic transcripts. Your friend simply needs to follow that process. No need to worry about being unprofessional or professional or anything like that. Just get the transcripts.

Comment: What about testimonies from professors, advisors, chair, and thesis/project supervisors? Even if the university is unresponsive (maybe the records clerk is inefficient and is struggling to respond to the emails, and that there is a long queue that needs to be cleared) there should be an unofficial transcript that your friend should be able to download from the university website. Get your friend to contact her supervisors/advisors and get them to contact university records directly. That will speed things up, and the request for transcript or other documents will be completed with urgency.

Comment: If your friend has completed a major thesis or essay, there should be some evidence of it in the university. Sometimes universities keep printed copies of the theses in their library; if your friend has one, that would be evidence that she has met the requirements for the degree. Convocation books/magazines list the names of all students (and their dept.) who graduated in the specific period. Your friend's name and details should be there.

Comment: Doesn't the university have a process for validating diplomas or records? Mine has an authentication key in the back

Comment: I really feel like there is more to this story that you have stated especially because you say, "Both the university and the org are saying this".  This is a RED FLAG because it's very easy to verify a univ. degree.  All that is needed is for the person to contact the university's registrar and request that an official transcript be sent to whoever needs it.  Most charge a small fee for this but the point is the univ. sends it directly.  If that's a problem then chances are the degree is indeed fake.

Comment: My university's records are digitized back to about the year after I graduated, so when a company calls, the university (student worker) will say they don't have any record of me.  I know to request official transcripts, and show them the actual diploma while waiting on that process.

Comment: So what does the certificate she took a picture of look like? If she has it why can't she show the original?  Short of that having the exact graduation date and proper spelling of her name should be enough information to verify with the school.

Comment: Has your friend requested a transcript via the standard process?

Comment: Did she receive an apology? If I was accused of faking a university degree, and proved that this is false, any decent person would apologise for that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Government degree verification in Canada often lacks quality**

I used to work for a governmental organization in Canada. I verified my degree with a picture of my diploma taken on my phone. That was how they checked your credentials.

I can easily see their idea of verification being emailing someone in admin at the university and them spelling the name wrong or going to the wrong department or asking for the wrong faculty or level or campus or year. Verification challenges have happened to quite a few friends.

Start by ordering an official transcript and ask HR for an address to send it. Universities all have some way to do this that is quick and easy.

Or just get on the phone with the Alumni office or the Registrar. Make them actually turn her down over the phone rather than ghosting her by email.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a no brainer - contact the college and get a copy.

Comment: Just to add: I can log into my university's online portal and print a proof of completion letter (similar to proof of enrolment letter), so that might be a good option. Ordering a transcript to be sent directly to the organization's HR department is probably still the best option.

Comment: Also, my experience is similar to yours when it comes to government degree verification in Canada. I went to an interview for a job at a federal department; the interviewer just asked to see my diploma over a video call. No proof-of-completion letter nor official transcripts required.

Comment: @sfxedit The key is get the University to mail directly to the employer. This removes any possibility of tamper, and it (should) be a basic request for any remotely decent institution.

Answer (score 6):

It should be a perfectly routine matter for any university to send you a transcript or to confirm that a degree was issued.  Give them the name that she was using at the time, and they'll find it and mail it to you.  But also – what did she *do* with the diploma when they handed it to her while she was wearing a cap and gown?  Where is that piece of paper now?

Comment: I have no clue where my physical diplomas are now. Maybe at my folks house, but they had a flood that may have wiped them out. Nobody has every asked for the actual diploma instead of an official transcript.

Answer (score 3):

So in my experience in getting international visas, it is a common function of the "Office of the Registrar" in Canadian Universities to send out sealed copies of final transcripts directly to whomever the alum requests.  I had to do this to get a work visa in Korea and every other foreign teacher I know had to as well.  Usually this fee is in the $30-50 range.

Honestly this seem like a fairly simple thing to sort out using the online portal for the university.  It should just be a matter of getting a copy of transcripts ordered to HR or the new hiring manager.  There shouldn't be any argument with an original issued directly from the issuing body.